# WPF UI Freezing when label is blinking

Tags: c#, wpf

When the label is blinking, the UI stops.

Style

```
##part of the code
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.2"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>   

<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="1">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="0">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

XAML source

```
<Label Tag="{Binding RepeatAuto}"/>
```

C# code:

```
RenewDisplay()
{
  .....
    Context.RepeatAuto = GetAutoCorrectOption(flg);
  .....
}
```

`RenewDisplay()` is called at regular intervals (timer) for screen (UI) update.

If the button is clicked while the label is flashing, the screen freezes.

This button stops the timer for about 3 seconds and then restarts it.
(Asynchronous communication with other applications)

There is no problem in the non-blinking state.

I don't know why this happens. Also, how to solve it.......

After the button logic is finished, run WPF Windows (any popup dialog), the UI moves again.

Comment: Have you done any debugging/profiling to check what the program is doing while frozen?

Comment: Each status is being updated internally, but the screen itself is in a freeze state.
Click the button on the screen (a pop-up appears), the UI moves again.

Only the UI is stopped, and button click events work normally.